# multiple key generation

Tags: php, key

I have code with me for key generation.

```
<?php   
function KeyGen()
{
 $keylength = 20;
 $key = md5(mktime());
 $new_key = '';
 for($i=1; $i <= $keylength; $i ++ )
    {
           $new_key .= $key[$i];
           if ( $i%5==0 && $i != $keylength) $new_key.='-';
    }
 return strtoupper($new_key);
 }
 echo KeyGen();
?>
```

i want to generate 20 keys. I am not getting how to do it.

Comment: So call the function 20 times

Comment: it give same key for 20 times

Comment: Well then don't use `md5(mktime())` which always uses the same current time for key generation. There's a `mt_rand()` function for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php   
 function KeyGen()
 {
 $keylength = 20;
 $key = md5(strtotime("now").rand());
 $new_key = '';
 for($i=1; $i <= $keylength; $i ++ )
   {
       $new_key .= $key[$i];
       if ( $i%5==0 && $i != $keylength) $new_key.='-';
   }
 return strtoupper($new_key);
 }
 $new_key= KeyGen();
 echo  $new_key;
 ?>
```

Call the function,You should get the key

Comment: i want set of keys. i tried it but it only give me single key as a output.

Comment: Try strtotime("now") insted of mktime()